# Serializing 3 Interconnected Django relational models

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to write a set of serializers for my models.  I want the serializer for the deck to spit out the cards that match the decks ID in the CardToDeck Model and then fetch the card matching the card_id in the Card Model and Ideally be able to write with the given solution.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class CardToDeck(models.Model):
    deck_id = models.ForeignKey("Deck", related_name="card_to_deck", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    card_id = models.ForeignKey("Card", related_name="card_to_deck", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Card(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    multiverseid = models.IntegerField(unique=True) # Used to fetch the card from the API
    name = models.CharField(max_length=145)


class Deck(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=145)
```

serializers.py:

```
from .models import *
from rest_framework import serializers


class CardSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Card
        fields = ('id', 'name')

class CardToDeckSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CardToDeck
        fields = ('deck_id', 'card_id')

# Serializer for Deck that grabs the nested model references
class DeckSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    cards = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=CardToDeck.objects.all(), many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Deck
        depth = 2
        fields = ('name', 'cards')
```

What I would like the JSON to look like:

```
{
    "name": "deckNameGoHere",
    "cards": [{"id":1, "name":"cardNameGoHere", "quantity":3},{"id":2, "name":"cardNameGoHere", "quantity":2}]
}
```

I just spent the last 4 hours trying to figure this out and feel quite dumb, any help would be appreciated. I looked into the docks but couldn't find the resources I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [DRF documents](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield):

> **PrimaryKeyRelatedField** may be used to represent the target of the
> relationship **using its primary key**.

You can use CardToDeckSerializer as DeckSerializer's field without PrimeryKeyRelated and as a serializer object if you want to read the data and bring it back:

```
from .models import *
from rest_framework import serializers


class CardSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Card
        fields = ('id', 'name')

class CardToDeckSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CardToDeck
        fields = ('deck_id', 'card_id')

# Serializer for Deck that grabs the nested model references
class DeckSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # if not intended to use bulk action it's better to keep the "many" fields as read only
    cards = CardToDeckSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Deck
        depth = 2
        fields = ('name', 'cards')
```

If you wanted to show a list of related linkes, you could use the following:

```
HyperlinkedRelatedField
```

I highly recommend reading [DRF's document on  nested Serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)

Comment: I was reading that but tried to apply it and the result is the code above. Close but no dice as they say. until I get some test data in this database I wont be able to fully verify which answer works best.

Comment: Let me know if it works. I've used this approach before and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `quantity` is in `CardToDeck`, you can do something like this:

```
class CardToDeckSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.CharField(source='card_id.id')
    name = serializers.CharField(source='card_id.name')

    class Meta:
        model = CardToDeck
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'quantity')


class DeckSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    cards = CardToDeckSerializer(source='card_to_deck' many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Deck
        fields = ('name', 'cards')
```

Comment: So you can use the . operator on the resolved card_id Model like "card_id.flavortext"

Comment: That's the foreign key that is in `CardToDeck`, so yes

Comment: And that the CardToDeckSerializer using this method can bypass the need for serializing the Card Class for the Deck class, I may serialize it later for defining the view of a single card but anyway, I will try it out.

Comment: Yes it was done this way to circumvent serializing one `Card` within `CardToDeck`, to match your expected output. Otherwise you need to go through `CardToDeck` to get to `Card`. The output that you will get for `cards` is essentially a list of `CardToDeck`s, but modified to display as if they are `Card`s

Comment: I cant verify if it is working because I cant add test data without writing some create methods. After I write those I will return to report.

Comment: OK cool. Do note that my answer here will not support writable nested serializers, (creating `CardToDeck` via `DeckSerializer`), so you might have to write a separate serializer for that, or modify the fields list here